# Using a loop to declare a Mat class

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

The camera stores images to a FTP server with the filename pattern as "folder"+"program_name"+ index +"format", where index is a number from one to almost ten billion (0000000001 to 9999999999). The path and filename are needed to display the images. It is required to show 10 images on OpenCV, so I tried to make the following testcode using the function [ShowManyImages](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/DisplayManyImages).

```
int main() {
int img_ini = 1;
std::string img_path = "../data/";
std::string img_name = "img";
std::string img_format = ".bmp";
std::string var;
var = img_path + img_name + std::to_string(img_ini) + img_format;

Mat img1 = imread(var);
Mat img2 = imread("../data/img2.bmp");
Mat img3 = imread("../data/img3.bmp");
Mat img4 = imread("../data/img4.bmp");
Mat img5 = imread("../data/img5.bmp");
Mat img6 = imread("../data/img6.bmp");
Mat img7 = imread("../data/img6.bmp");
Mat img8 = imread("../data/img6.bmp");
Mat img9 = imread("../data/img6.bmp");
Mat img10 = imread("../data/img6.bmp");
ShowManyImages("Image", 10, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9, img10);

return 0;
}
```

To this point i could show the image 1 creating the `var` variable. However, this code is a mess and i didn't want to create `img1,img2, ..., img10`.

So i tried to make something similar to what was done with `var` to the [Mat](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) img, creating a loop like For i=1 To 10  `Mat img + i = imread(img_path + img_name + std::to_string(img_ini + i) + img_format;)`. But wasn't able, because Mat () isn't as imread ().

- Is there a way to make something like the for loop described?
- Or is it better to create a void function like:

  ```
  Mat img1 = imread(var(1));
  Mat img2 = imread(var(2));
  Mat img3 = imread(var(3));
  Mat img4 = imread(var(4));
  Mat img5 = imread(var(5));
  Mat img6 = imread(var(6));
  Mat img7 = imread(var(7));
  Mat img8 = imread(var(8));
  Mat img9 = imread(var(9));
  Mat img10 = imread(var(10));
  ```
- Or is there another/better way?

Comment: Arrays and/or vectors play very nicely with loops.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a vector of Mats.  There are a few ways to load them and in show them.

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> myMatArray;
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPicturesToLoad; i++){
   std::string imgToLoad = img_path + img_name + std::to_string(i) + img_format;
   cv::Mat temp = imread(imageToLoad);
   myMatArray.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: @tobi303 Well, there is an overload, for [`std::string::operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) which takes in a `char` as an `rhs` (overload #5 in the above documentation). So, the compiler might just call that, while issuing warning about narrowing conversion. It doesn't do what OP would expect, tho (because, it would result in, most likely, unprintable character being appended to the `std::string`).

Comment: Since C++11, it is possible to add an int to a string with std::to_string (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).  I fixed the omission in my example code.  I added the std::to_string to the int as one possible way to do the conversion, and was the method used by the OP in their attempt.

Comment: @Mepix Thanks, it worked! Just had to add a change to the function showManyImages from `void ShowManyImages(string title, int nArgs, ...)` to `int showManyImages(const String winName, const std::vector<cv::Mat> images)`.